# Can't get my bullet pointed ul's to sit side by side

Tags: html, css

I've been trying and trying and can't find a way to get by two bullet point lists to sit side by side.

Here is the live page: http://kaleshe.github.io/sharing-is-caring/

Here's the code for the whole section:

```
        <span class="anchor"><a name="whatisdepression"</a></span>
        <div id="content-container">
            <section id="first" class="content">
                <h2>What is depression?</h2>
                    <p>Depression is not just feeling down or sad, it's more than that.
                    A person experiencing depression will experience intense, negative emotions such as; anxiety, hopelessness, 
                        negativity and helplessness, these emotions stay with them instead of going away. Depression can be quite difficult 
                        to spot, many people who have depression do not even realise it themselves.</p>

                <h3 id="sas" class="banner">Signs & Symptoms</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Fatigue and loss of energy</li>
                        <li>Constant sadness</li>
                        <li>Loss of self-confidence 
                            and self-esteem</li>
                        <li>Difficulty concentrating</li>
                        <li>Loss of pleasure in activities</li>
                        <li>Feeling anxious all the time</li>
                        <li>Feelings of helplessness 
                            and hopelesness</li>
                    </ul>   
                    <ul id="right">
                        <li>Excessive feelings of guilt 
                            or worthlessness</li>
                        <li>Avoiding others</li>
                        <li>Finding it hard to function</li>
                        <li>Loss of appetite</li>
                        <li>Loss of sex drive</li>
                        <li>Physical aches and pains</li>
                        <li>Suicidal thoughts</li>  
                        <li>Self-harm</li>
                    </ul>

                <h3 id="wci" class="banner">What causes it?</h3>
                    <p>A number of different factors can increase the chance of a person becoming depressed; such as difficult 
                    events and experiences that lower their spirits, instead of their spirits rising naturally as they should, 
                    they stick around much longer and become problematic. It is also possible to feel down without there being 
                    an obvious reason.</p>
            </section>
```

Here is the *relevant* CSS:

```
body {
    margin: auto 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content, nav {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.content {
    height: 1080px;
    max-width: 1560px;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.banner {
    background-color: #000e2d;
    color: #fff;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 100px;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

#secondbg {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In your site there is only two `ul` - one is menu and second is *emo kid* text. Please provide SO Snippet with your **sample** code. Also your *relevant* code does not select your `ul` at all. In site fix line #29 `<span class="anchor"><a name="whatisdepression"</a></span>` - not closing `<a` tag

Comment: In the first section there is a set of bullet-points that I divided into two <ul> and I've shown that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two `ul` in a separate div and then apply `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/axquqnnc/)

```css
body {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.content,
nav {
  font-size: .95em;
  /* for demo */
}
.menu-wrap ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  height: 1080px;
  max-width: 1560px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* for demo */
}
.banner {
  background-color: #000e2d;
  color: #fff;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.09em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#secondbg {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="anchor"><a href="#first"></a></span>
<div id="content-container">
  <section id="first" class="content">
    <h2>What is depression?</h2>
    <p>Depression is not just feeling down or sad, it's more than that. A person experiencing depression will experience intense, negative emotions such as; anxiety, hopelessness, negativity and helplessness, these emotions stay with them instead of going
      away. Depression can be quite difficult to spot, many people who have depression do not even realise it themselves.</p>

    <h3 id="sas" class="banner">Signs & Symptoms</h3>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <ul>
        <li>Fatigue and loss of energy</li>
        <li>Constant sadness</li>
        <li>Loss of self-confidence and self-esteem</li>
        <li>Difficulty concentrating</li>
        <li>Loss of pleasure in activities</li>
        <li>Feeling anxious all the time</li>
        <li>Feelings of helplessness and hopelesness</li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="right">
        <li>Excessive feelings of guilt or worthlessness</li>
        <li>Avoiding others</li>
        <li>Finding it hard to function</li>
        <li>Loss of appetite</li>
        <li>Loss of sex drive</li>
        <li>Physical aches and pains</li>
        <li>Suicidal thoughts</li>
        <li>Self-harm</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3 id="wci" class="banner">What causes it?</h3>

    <p>A number of different factors can increase the chance of a person becoming depressed; such as difficult events and experiences that lower their spirits, instead of their spirits rising naturally as they should, they stick around much longer and become
      problematic. It is also possible to feel down without there being an obvious reason.</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: `inline-block` without `width` will cause the next `ul` to drop if more content is added in first `ul` as in this case. If you open this in small screens you will see that 2nd ul is dropping

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` with `width` on `ul` with following styles and structure.

```
<div class="list-holder">
    <ul>
        // liste items will go here..
    </ul>
    <ul>
        // liste items will go here..
    </ul>
</div>

.list-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.list-holder {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: auto 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content, nav {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.content {
    height: 1080px;
    max-width: 1560px;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.banner {
    background-color: #000e2d;
    color: #fff;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 100px;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

#secondbg {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.list-holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-holder ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="anchor"><a name="whatisdepression"</a></span>
        <div id="content-container">
            <section id="first" class="content">
                <h2>What is depression?</h2>
                    <p>Depression is not just feeling down or sad, it's more than that.
                    A person experiencing depression will experience intense, negative emotions such as; anxiety, hopelessness, 
                        negativity and helplessness, these emotions stay with them instead of going away. Depression can be quite difficult 
                        to spot, many people who have depression do not even realise it themselves.</p>

                <h3 id="sas" class="banner">Signs & Symptoms</h3>
                <div class="list-holder">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Fatigue and loss of energy</li>
                        <li>Constant sadness</li>
                        <li>Loss of self-confidence 
                            and self-esteem</li>
                        <li>Difficulty concentrating</li>
                        <li>Loss of pleasure in activities</li>
                        <li>Feeling anxious all the time</li>
                        <li>Feelings of helplessness 
                            and hopelesness</li>
                    </ul>   
                    <ul>
                        <li>Excessive feelings of guilt 
                            or worthlessness</li>
                        <li>Avoiding others</li>
                        <li>Finding it hard to function</li>
                        <li>Loss of appetite</li>
                        <li>Loss of sex drive</li>
                        <li>Physical aches and pains</li>
                        <li>Suicidal thoughts</li>  
                        <li>Self-harm</li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>

                <h3 id="wci" class="banner">What causes it?</h3>
                    <p>A number of different factors can increase the chance of a person becoming depressed; such as difficult 
                    events and experiences that lower their spirits, instead of their spirits rising naturally as they should, 
                    they stick around much longer and become problematic. It is also possible to feel down without there being 
                    an obvious reason.</p>
            </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add:

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If that's for the list's only. If you want the titles too, then add a container around the list and the title for both of them and apply the style - display: inline-block; to that. Take the example below using a class wrapper of .list-wrap

```
.list-wrap ul {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you very much